# Turn on computer with USB keyboard through PS/2 adapter

Tags: usb, keyboard, bios, wake-up

I want to wake-up [my PC](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/P67AGD65_B3.html#hero-overview) by [USB keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000/b2m-00012) connected through PS/2 adapter. According to BIOS settings:

> Resume From S3/S4/S5 by PS/2 keyboard ... [Any Key]

it should be working, but doesn't.

If I connect USB mouse as I did for keyboard & set up in BIOS:

> Resume From S3/S4/S5 by PS/2 Mouse ... [Enabled]

it works - PC wakes-up when I pressed a mouse button.

Is it possible to wake up my PC with my keyboard?

Comment: Check PS/2 standby power jumpers on the motherboard. Try another keyboard. Try to light some of the Caps/Num/Scroll-Lock lights and get you PC into standby - if the lights go off then either your motherboard or your keyboard does not support this mode. Your keyboard may require more power than your motherboard supplies in standby mode. It is also possible that your motherboard resets your keyboard before turning it off, so the keyboard cannot properly detect if it is connected to PS/2 or USB port.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are missing Chipset Driver, Try installing latest chipset drivers of your motherboard and check it.

Also if your mother board is of Biostar you can check the following question

> How to use keyboard or mouse to power on or resume the motherboard?
>
> If use USB keyboard or mouse, press Delete key in POST screen to go CMOS> Advanced> Power Configuration> USB wakeup From S3/S4 set this function Enabled.
>   Also need to set JSUBV1 and JUSBV2 to pin 2-3 for motherboard to provide 5V stand-by power to USB devices for resume.
>
> If need to power on motherboard through PS2 keyboard or mouse, press Delete key in POST screen to go CMOS> Advanced> SuperIO Configuration> Keyboard PowerOn / Mouse PowerOn. Set these two functions to Enabled.
>   Save the CMOS setting and make sure system reboot once to POST screen then use power switch to turn off system power.
>   It will be able to use keyboard or mouse for power on at S4 or S5 condition.
>
> Note: Turn off PSU power source or unplug the power cord will cause PS2 keyboard or mouse power on function fail. This function will be able to use again after system reboot once.
>   src= http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/support/faq_content.php?S_ID=459

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP has a **MSI** mobo. You didn't even read the question.

Comment: @guest, Yes you are correct I didn't notice that he has added his PC config details, But I also has asked him to install his chipset driver and check it OP has to comment for this.

Comment: Windows is already shipped with generic drivers. What specific chipset driver do you think is missing? And what does it has to do with the question at hand?

Comment: that is what sometimes generic drivers wouldn't work as expected and not enable critical functionality, with each motherboard will get vendor specific drivers included in the package. I'm asking him to try once installing that I'm just guessing that it will work if he install that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a USB-PS/2 adapter then the computer sees the attached keyboard and mouse as USB devices, not PS/2 devices.  Pressing a mouse button to wake the machine likely works and the keyboard does not because of some other setting elsewhere, as in the USB keyboard and mouse settings.  Change the USB settings to match your desired behavior or use the PS/2 ports on the computer, as opposed to ones on a USB adapter.

Comment: Re *"If you are using a USB-PS/2 adapter then the computer sees the attached keyboard and mouse as USB devices, not PS/2 devices."*: That seems unlikely. Does a PS/2 port carry USB signals? Do you have a source?